# d3 remove data using exit

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've prepared a small fiddle to illustrate the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zhFbn/)

I'm having an issue using d3's exit function to remove elements from the dom.

Say I have an array of 10 elements:

```
var data = [1 ,4, 5, 6, 24, 8, 12, 1, 1, 20]
```

I use this data to create a simple horizontal bar chart using d3

```
d3.selectAll('rect') 
.data(data) 
.enter() 
.attr("class", "rectangle")
.attr("stroke", "black")
.attr("stroke-width","1px")
.attr("fill","none")
.attr("x", 0)
.attr("y", function(d, i) { return 25 * i; } )
.attr("width", function(d) { return 22 * d; } )
.attr("height", "20");
```

Now after a short delay I'd like to prune my dataset so all that I have left is

```
var truncatedData = [4,5]

d3.selectAll('rect')
    .data(truncatedData )   
    .exit()
    .transition()
    .delay(3000)
    .remove();
```

Data is removed successfully but it still shows the first two elements 1,4 instead of 4,5.

How can I remove all but [4,5] from the dom?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By default, d3 matches elements given to `.data()` by their index and not value. That is, giving it a two-element array in the second call means that the first two elements from the first call (indices 0 and 1) are retained.

To fix this issue in your case, give a function to match elements to the second call to `.data()`, i.e.

```
.data([5, 6], function(d) { return(d); })
```

Fixed jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zhFbn/2/).

Comment: OP is also joining data to rects the first time, and then to the groups the second time.

Comment: @gumballhead - Yes, I changed it a bit for simplicity, but the problem still stands in either scenario.

Comment: That is correct, but I rather recommand you to define a name function, and binding every element to a unique name as a key.